# Check depositing

Tags: checking-account, deposits

My utility department sent me back some of my security deposit; however the check is made out to both me and my ex.(who I don’t know his where abouts) so it’s pay to order of said person and then address is c/o my name and address (since his where abouts is unknown). What do I do? Can I deposit it into my account or does he have to endorse it?

Comment: Clarification: Are both your names on the Pay To line or just his? If you're *only* on the check as the C/O, then that's not your check.

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense. It’s confusing how it’s printed. It’s such a small amount not really even worth the bother. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 6):

Technically, legally, if it's made out to you AND him, then you both must endorse it. It's possible that if you just endorsed it yourself that the bank would accept the deposit. It just depends how finicky they're going to be about it. If you called the bank and asked, they would almost surely say that both signatures are required, but if you dropped it in an ATM with only your signature, they MIGHT just accept it.

You say you don't know where he is, which would presumably make it difficult to get his signature.

Probably the legally and morally right thing to do is contact the utility and tell them that your ex no longer lives here. If they refuse to send a check in your name only, perhaps they can credit the amount to your bill.

Comment: I did contact the utility company and that is how the check was sent because they sent it to the account holder. They already credited the amount on the last bill. Before it was disconnected. Thanks for your reply though. It’s really not an amount worth making a headache over

Comment: Why is the account still in both your names? Getting the account put solely in your name now may not affect to whom the refund is due, but it will avoid problems like this in the future.